# How to add a screenshot on a test failure using Appium and WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, allure

I currently have multiple wdio.config files due to the multiple apps in my end to end suite

it looks like this and all these files have the allure reporting command in it and my reports are working fine:

[image]

every file has an allure reporting command like this:

```
 reporters: [['allure', {
        outputDir: 'allure-results',
        disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
        disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: true,
    }]],
```

and also the desired capabilities like this:

```
capabilities: {
        App: {
            port: 4723,
            capabilities: {
                platformName: 'iOS',
                'appium:platformVersion': '13.6',
                'appium:orientation': 'PORTRAIT',
                'appium:noReset': true,
                'appium:newCommandTimeout': 240,
                "appium:platformName": "iOS",
                "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 8",
                "appium:bundleId": "com.app",
            }
        },
    },
```

and i also have a separate general wdio file which a general file and have not added much in it.

```
  afterStep: function (test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
    if (error) {
      browser.takeScreenshot();
    }
  }
```

I have tried adding the after hook in the custom wdio config file as well but i am not able to have the screenshot on failure. i have also used `App.takeScreenshot();` command as well instead of using `browser.takeScreenshot();` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about appium part but below code as you also have used in wdio.conf.js (or may be custom wdio file) works in webdriverio. I have used it in my framework.

```
afterTest: function(test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
    if (!passed) {
        browser.takeScreenshot();
    }
},
```

Comment: User created appium driver instead browser and use saveScreenShot instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 afterTest: async function (test) {
        browser.saveScreenshot("browserfull.png")
// OR
        driver.saveScreenshot("driverfull.png")

      }
```